# Where should I place a .env for production

Tags: jenkins, deployment, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have a webapi build in Flask and I am using aws elastic beanstalk to serve my app.
I was integrating Jenkins for CI/CD and this is what my pipelie does:

1. fetch the code
2. Build docker image
3. Push docker image to Docker hub
4. Deploy docker image to aws (Docker hub to aws).

All the steps above work as expected but I just have a question related to the .env vars.

If  wanted to have different environments, (production/development) Where should I place the .env file that my webapi uses. For development everyone can have their own .env file but for production not everyone should access these variables. Having said that where could I place this .env file so that when my pipeline starts I can get these vars to deploy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure the environment variables in the AWS elastic beanstalk dashboard of your created app. You should see Environment variables under software configuration section.